# Мне нужно разместить 20 на 20 ячеек с нумерацией

Tags: css3, angular2

Мне нужно разместить  20 на 20 ячеек с нумерацией.
как то так
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
3  1 2 3 4 5
4  1 2 3 4 5

И т.д
Как посоветуете  это сделать на ангуляре. Чтобы простым перебором не  делать.
P.S И там ячейки  должны быть возле цифр. И я думаю увеличивать или уменьшать количество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это дело можно организовать через CSS, `counter()`. А блоки не обязательно должны быть основными, это могут быть мелкие блоки именно для чисел. Условно, так:

```css
.mama {
  counter-reset: bubu;
  counter-increment: mama;  
  /****/ border: 2px solid orange; margin: 10px;
}
.mama::before {
  content: counter( mama ) "→ ";
  /****/ font-size: 30px; color: red;
}

.bubu {
  counter-increment: bubu;  
  /****/ border: 1px solid #05a; display: inline-block; margin: 15px 5px 0 0; width: 50px;
}

.bubu::before {
  content: counter( bubu ) ". ";
}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
</div>

<div class="mama">
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
</div>

<div class="mama">
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
</div>

<div class="mama">
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
  <div class="bubu"></div>
</div>
```